# Adding Global Styles with Xamarin.Forms Application Made with Prism Template Pack

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I created an app using the Prism Template Pack to create a new Xamarin.Forms project. But unfortunately I could not style my app.

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
         x:Class="StyleThisOneAlso.App">
        <Application.Resources>

        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

But doing those doesn't turn the labels to green.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio 2017? I just switched from 2015 to 2017 and the global styles seem to be not working anymore.

Comment: I actually made a mistake. I am using Xamarin Live Player to test my app that's why it isn't working. I read that the live player doesn't support third-party libraries such as Prism which is what I am using. When I debug my app, the styles work again